# Why this code doesn't work inside function?

Tags: javascript

why innerHTML or alert() doesn't work when it is in a function? Except for the function, everything works. :(

```
<div id="123"></div>
```

```js
function example()
{
    document.getElementById('123').innerHTML = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once you have declare the function you have to call it

```
<div id="123"></div>
function example(){ document.getElementById('123').innerHTML = "test"; } //function declaration

example(); //function call
```

Answer (score 3):

This is only a function declaration. You need to call this function:

```
example()
```

Comment: And for clarity it needs to be called after that element exists